# Issue with EJB/JSF2.0

Tags: jsf-2, ejb

I'm currently practicing JSF and EJB, but right now I can't get the page to show the information requested, this have input text and submit button (input.xhtml) and the expected result is to show the text submitted.

```
/input.xhtml @16,56 value="#{welcome.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'welcome' resolved to null
```

I've tried everything to fix it, this is part of the input.xthml

```
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputText value="Name:"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{welcome.name}" title="name" id="name"
                                 required="true" />
                    <h:message for="name" style="color: red"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:commandButton action="show" value="submit"/>
            </h:form>

        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>
```

This is the bean.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Welcome {
    private String name;
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The code looks fine and it should work just fine. I only don't see how this is related to JPA and EJB. You would have exactly the same problem when you removed JPA/EJB from your testcase, right? You can just leave those tags and this detail out of the question.

As to the concrete problem, because you omitted the `import` declarations, I can given the symptoms only guess that you're actually importing `@ManagedBean` from the [`javax.annotation` package](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/ManagedBean.html) instead of the [`javax.faces.bean` package](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html). The former won't make the bean to be managed by JSF, but the latter wil do. Check and fix your imports. Note that the `@RequestScoped` also needs to be from [the same package](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/RequestScoped.html), not from the [`javax.enterprise.context` package](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html).

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Welcome {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
write like this

@ManagedBean(name="welcome")
@RequestScoped
public class welcome implements Serializable {
private String name;
}

In html write like this
<h:inputText value="#{welcome.name}" title="name" id="name"
                                 required="true" />
```